# How do I check if the list contains empty elements?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Suppose I have a empty string, it will be split:

```
>>>''.split(',')
['']
```

The result of the split is `['']`. I use `bool` to check it whether or not it's empty. It will return `True`.

```
>>>bool([''])
True
```

How do I check the split result is empty?

Comment: I see. it's not a empty list. I hope I would exclude the situation. I am thinking how to do.

Comment: Ultimately, what are you trying to do? There's no point in trying to split an empty list in the first place, you could gate this code with an if-statement or if-expression in a list comprehension: `if s1: s2 = s1.split(',') ...`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With `bool([''])` you're checking if the list `['']` has any contents, *which it does*, the contents just happen to be the empty string `''`.

If you want to check whether *all* the elements in the list aren't 'empty' (so if the list contains the string `''` it will return `False`) you can use the built-in function **[`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#all)**:

```
all(v for v in l)
```

This takes every element `v` in list `l` and checks if it has a `True` value; if **all** elements do it returns `True` if at least one doesn't it returns `False`. As an example:

```
l = ''.split(',')

all(v for v in l)
Out[75]: False
```

You can substitute this with **[`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any)** to perform a partial check and  see if *any of the items* in the list `l` have a value of `True`.

A more comprehensive example* with both uses:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, '']

all(l)
# '' doesn't have a True value
Out[82]: False

# 1, 2, 3 have a True value
any(l)
Out[83]: True
```

---

*As *[@ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger)* pointed out in the comments, the same exact thing can be done with `all(l)` or `any(l)` since they both just accept an iterable in the end.

Comment: Simplification: Change `all(v for v in l)` to just `all(l)`; no need to make a special generator expression when `all` can process the `list` directly.

Comment: Also, you inverted `all` and `any`; `all` tells you if all the results were non-empty, not if it has non-empty elements,and `any` says if it has non-empty elements (it could still have empty, but if `any` returns `True`, at least one was non-empty). `any` is probably more useful here.

Comment: It does not work if the elements contains value `False`, sample `all([1, 2, 3, False])`, False returns as result.

Comment: @Ivan that does what it is supposed to do. Since they *all* don't have a Truthy value it returns `False`.

Answer (score 2):

If emptiness is the important result, probably best to test the original string first:

```
x = ''
if x:
    # Original string was non-empty, split it
    splitx = x.split(',')
    if any(splitx):
        # There was at least one character in the original string that wasn't a comma
```

The first test rules out empty initial strings, the second one using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) rules out strings that were nothing but the split character, and therefore returned a whole bunch of empty strings, but no non-empty strings. As long as you got one non-empty string, it passes.

Note: In case you're trying to parse CSV files, don't use `.split(',')`; there is a [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) that handles this correctly (including escapes, quoting, etc.), and should *ALWAYS* be used for parsing CSV, never roll your own parser. Added bonus: `csv` will convert `''` inputs to `[]` rows, which you can test for truthiness directly, not to `['']` like `str.split` does. Example:

```
>>> import csv, io

>>> f = io.StringIO('\n\na,b,c\n1,2,3\n\n')
>>> [row for row in csv.reader(f) if row]  # Stripping easily
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', '3']]
```

vs. the same approach with `str.split(',')` which still doesn't handle quoting, escaping, etc.:

```
>>> f = io.StringIO('\n\na,b,c\n1,2,3\n\n')
>>> stripped = (line.rstrip('\r\n') for line in f)  # Must manually strip line endings first
>>> [line.split(',') for line in stripped if line]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', '3']]
```

Answer (score 1):

The split result isn't empty. The sense of "emptiness" you're looking for is best checked by looking at the original, unsplit string:

```
if not original_string:
    # It's empty.
```

But if you really want to look at the split result for this:

```
if len(split_result) == 1 and not split_result[0]:
    # It's "empty".
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case it truly isnt empty

If you want to check if the element within that list is empty you can do:

```
string = ''.split(',')

if not string[0]:
    print "empty"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`str.split()` documentation,](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) *"Splitting an empty string with a specified separator returns ['']."*

To check for this case, when you are using an explicit delimiter (like your use of `split(",")`), do something like this:

```
l = s.split(",")

if len(l) == 1 and l[0] == '':
    print("string was empty")
```